# css vertically aligning spans

Tags: css

I'm trying to keep everything aligned vertically but can't seem to figure it out

here is the css

```
fieldset span{
    padding:50px 10px 0px 10px;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
}
fieldset span.buttons{
    float:right;
}
```

and the html markup

```
<fieldset class="remove">
    <span class="itemtype">story</span>
    <span class="itemtype">53547</span>
    <span class="title">New online education program aimed at curbing dangerous drinking</span>
    <span class="buttons">
        <a href="#" target="blank"><img src="img/edit.png" alt="edit story" />Edit</a>
        <a href="#7" target="blank"><img src="http://www.bibliomania.com/graphics/read.gif" alt="read story" />Read</a>
    </span>
    <input type="hidden" name="featured[items][53547]" value="story" />
</fieldset>
```

and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/SxCH2/)  you can see how the image pushes down also the text in the 'a' tag text needs to be corrected as well

**edit**

using background image would be nice but that makes the image go under the text see [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/WZvWd/)

Comment: How would you like it to be aligned ? To me, these elements are aligned, on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just using the padding for both top & bottom:

```
fieldset span{
    padding:25px 10px 25px 10px;
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SxCH2/5/

Comment: this still doesn't put everything in a nice neath row see how the links and images are not in line with the rest

Comment: Updated my friend. I removed the image tag and place them with CSS. Just give each link an id to differentiate. http://jsfiddle.net/SxCH2/6/

Comment: that looks awesome thanks and actually padding only needs to be 10px

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
fieldset span a img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

`Vertical-align` is a CSS property that is often misued to align text. However its aim is to align images (and yes, it also does align text but only in `table`).

See [CSS-tricks.com - What is vertical-align](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)

[Fiddle to test](http://jsfiddle.net/sGgZb/2/)

Comment: if i change your fiddle to use middle instead of basline the links look better but the button span is still lower than the other spans

Comment: yeah, because page width is smaller than spans width

Comment: you should set fixed or min width of `fieldset`

Comment: ahh, right, it's still lower about 3px, due to image. Just use `background-image` instead - easy to position and all icons in one file.

Comment: @atlavis thank you for pointing the wrong link, I fixed it. Button is lower because of the tiny width available for the page. Also the background-image isn't a so bad solution.